# PHP: Best practice for accessing a class everywhere in a project?

Tags: php

I'm self taught & unsure on how to do this, need to access a single instance of my config class, everywhere. Could use a DIC to inject everywhere, but I want it to work dynamically.

I could make the class static, but is that the answer? A DIC could be useless here even. I would be extreemly grateful if someone could give me some advice here. Looking for a clean way, not dirty.

Here is my current setup for injecting into controllers, for things like templating.

```
$controllerRule = [
    "constructParams" => [$dice->create("App\Providers\Template")],    
    "shared" => true,
];

$dice->addRule("App\Controllers\Frontend\LandingController", $controllerRule);
```

Here is how I'm currently creating the instance of Config, with my DIC.

```
$configRule = [
    "constructParams" => ["example"],
    "shared" => true,
];

$dice->addRule("App\Providers\Configuration", $configRule);
```

Comment: You may want to autoload classes: https://www.tinywebhut.com/autoloading-class-files-in-php-54

Comment: If you really need to access it 'everywhere', all the time, then you could make it a global. Nothing wrong with that. There are lots of globals in PHP. However if you don't always need it, then dependency injection, or a DIC, is better. I would suggest to use it, since you seem to have one, and you never know what the future brings. The answer to your question also depends on what the code will be used for, and how it is shared with others.

Comment: @Saral auto loading has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I need it in my template class, and all my controllers. It'll then be assigned to the template to be used in views, I can't think of anywhere else it'll be required.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice? *Don't*.

Ask yourself this: Does a class that needs the Config instance require access to *all* configuration options?

Instead of:

```
class HomeController {

    private $numberOfItemsShown;

    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->numberOfItemsShown = $config->get('homepage.number_of_items');
    }

}
```

Do this:

```
class HomeController {

    private $numberOfItemsShown;

    public function __construct(int $numberOfItemsShown) {
        $this->numberOfItemsShown = $numberOfItemsShown;
    }

}
```

If a class requires *many* constructor params, you have a couple of options.

- Pass an associative array ("options" array)
- Split the class into several
- If the parameters have a common concept, create a new class (e.g. instead of "userPassword", "userName", "userEmail", pass a User class that has the others as its properties)

A general rule of thumb is that a class should *ask* for its configuration, not retrieve it.